# usage of "lead to"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, idioms

If I want to use *lead to*, does it always need to use *being* as shown below.

> less number of points *lead to* missing edges *being* occurred, are
>   recognized using proximity analysis.

Comment: Is that intended to be a complete sentence? It doesn't make sense as it stands. I'd guess at _[Using] a lower number of points will lead to a number of edges being missed; this will be picked up on by the use of proximity analysis._ _Lead to_ may be followed by a noun phrase or a structure containing an -ing-form: ...will lead to disaster // ...wil lead to some edges being missed.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: thank you for the comments. Actually I wanted to write the following meaning with the term lead to. "The cases where missing edges occur due to less number of points are recognized using proximity analysis".

Comment: "Fewer points" or "a smaller number of points" is correct. =>  "Cases in which there are missing edges occur because fewer points are recognized using proximity analysis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to phrase your sentence(the complete one posted in the comments) using "lead to" is:

> Proximity analysis recognizes cases in which fewer points lead to missing edges.

There are obviously many other ways to rephrase the sentence such as:

> Fewer points lead to cases where edges are missed; however, these are recognized by proximity analysis.

I personally prefer the former over the latter.

Comment: The rephrase needs re-punctuating.

Comment: is it missing a comma before "however"?

Comment: A semi-colon, dash or full stop.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me there. Always eager to learn :D